# Poor performance Insert statement when select view contain dblink

Tags: oracle, insert-into, dblink, hint

I'm in some troubles with an Insert statement in oracle 12.2.
I have the query like this:

```
INSERT INTO LOCAL.TABLE_1 ( column1, column2....) 
SELECT  column1, column2
FROM (BLOCK CODE WITH SELECT AND INNER JOIN)
(
INNER JOIN (SELECT columnx, columny, columnz,columna, columnb...
FROM (SELECT columnx, columny, columnz FROM LOCAL.ViewA WHERE....) S
INNER JOIN (SELECT columna, columnb FROM LOCAL.ViewB WHERE....)D 
ON ..... )
)A WHERE b = 1;
```

And the query of ViewA and B like this:

```
Select columnA, columnB, columnC FROM REMOTE.CUSTOMERS@DBLCUSTOMER;
```

The troubles are:

- Hint not work for Insert statement like APPEND, Driving_Site, Parallel even Nologing. It took nearly 2 hours for 2 million records to insert from remote to local table. 
  I tried debug, the select statement just take only 8s to get 2 million records from remote table.
- Can any hint work for ViewA and ViewB? It's very bad performance when I using hint such as Driving_Site(It's good performance if I not use). I can't use dblink instead of View on block code because of company rule.

Is there any solution improve performance in this case?

Comment: There is no magical hint you can just use to make things faster. You need to look at the execution plan for the insert statement. If you say that running the whole query (minus the select) takes only 8 seconds, examine the execution plan for that query as well and compare. Also, in the execution plan you will find the number of rows Oracle is expecting to get from the remote tables; compare these cardinalities with the actual number of rows in the remote tables - you may find that adding `CARDINALITY` hints with appropriate values may improve things.

Comment: Note that querying a view instead of querying the remote table directly should not cause any difference.

Comment: @Maybe I couldn't clear my words. 
SELECT statement took 8s to get all records from remote table(more than 2million records). And insert them into local table took nearly 2h, so the insert statement is reason for bad performance. I tried add hints but It made the performance more bad than not use.

Comment: "Note that querying a view instead of querying the remote table directly should not cause any difference".
Thanks for this advice, I'll discuss with my boss about this.

Comment: You say the whole SELECT statement takes 8 secs and the INSERT takes 2 hours. That sounds wrong. There is an overhead to inserting but it's nothing like that. Now your insert could **hang** for two hours if some other long-running process had locked the entire table for that length of time, but that seems like any easy thing you could find out. anyway, as with most tuning problems, the gold lies in the specific details: there's not much we can do to help you without way more information.

Answer (score 1):

my comment for you is too long for a comment, so here you have it as an answer, even though this is no 'here is your fix' kind of answer. I have two ideas for you. HTH

1. maybe when you say the SELECT takes only 2 seconds, you are not fetching all rows but only the first 50? If you use Oracle SQL Developer, you can click the result set and then press Ctrl+A to see how long fetching all rows takes.
2. About your hints not working and the select taking longer when it is part of an insert, I can provide this quote from here: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/distributed-dml/

> A distributed DML statement must execute on the database where the DML target resides. The DRIVING_SITE hint cannot override this.

So in a distributed DML scenario, oracle pulls over everything (base table data before the joins) and does the joins etc locally. But there is hope, quoting the same link:

> If you want to make this example join remotely, you’ll have to create a join view at the remote site, and query the view.

Here is how I do it. This example is for an active DG where I want all the workload on the DG and on the RDS only the insert takes place and only the lines for the insert are transferred over the DB link:

```
-- RDS
-- First we create the results table on the RDS
create table your_schema.your_table [...]


-- RDS (Due to DG I have to create it on RDS and it makes it's way to the DG)
-- Now we create a VIEW with your huge long running query
create view your_schema.your_view as
select  [...];  -- your huge long running query is here


-- DG
-- Now you fill the RDS Table you created. As the results come from a VIEW and the query is executed on DG, all the workload is done on DG
insert into your_schema.your_table@DBLINK_TO_RDS
select  * from your_schema.your_view;
commit;
```

In the execution plan on RDS you then see that all work is done on DG. You only see 'load table conventional' and 'remote'. And in the execution plan on DG you see all the big joins and stuff.

You can also check active_session_history for workload produced on each system:

```
select 
sum(TM_DELTA_TIME), sum(TM_DELTA_CPU_TIME), sum(TM_DELTA_DB_TIME), sum(DELTA_READ_IO_REQUESTS), sum(DELTA_WRITE_IO_REQUESTS), sum(DELTA_READ_IO_BYTES),
sum(DELTA_WRITE_IO_BYTES), sum(DELTA_INTERCONNECT_IO_BYTES), max(PGA_ALLOCATED), max(TEMP_SPACE_ALLOCATED)
from gv$active_session_history where session_id = 3X5 and SESSION_SERIAL# = 2XXX0 and SAMPLE_ID > 4XXXXX6 and sample_id <= 4XXXXX9;
```